# How to pass variable arguments to expect

Tags: expect, parameter

I want to pass a variable number of arguments to a expect script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set timeout 10

spawn ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" [lindex $argv 0]@[lindex $argv 2]
expect "password: "
send "[lindex $argv 1]\n"
expect "$ "

for {set i 1} {$i < [llength $argv]} {incr i 1} {
   send { echo $i }
}
```

I want to get

```
1
2
3
```

But instead I get

```
echo $i
echo $i
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tcl has 2 sorts of string quoting: double-quotes, within which `$variable` is interpolated (replaced by the value), and braces, within which very little is changed at all. So in `send { echo $i }`, the string passed to the `send` command is `echo $i`. Instead, `send "echo $i\n"` would pass the string `echo 1` (and a newline) when `i` is 1, and so on.